# Trying to show confirmation popup on Gridview selected index change

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, gridview

I am trying to show a popup on `Gridview Selected index changed`.

Message `DO you want to Submit?`. If I press ok then do some work or If I cancel then do nothing remain on same page.

//Gridview

```
 <asp:GridView ID="gvCustomers" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" Font-Names="Arial"  AutoGenerateSelectButton="True" 
  Font-Size="10pt" RowStyle-BackColor="White" OnSelectedIndexChanged="gvCustomers_SelectedIndexChanged" 
  Cssclass="gvv table table-striped table-bordered">
   <HeaderStyle CssClass="bg-clouds"  BackColor ="#9c27b0"  ForeColor ="white"/>
     <Columns>
       <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="150px" DataField="T_NO" HeaderText="T_NO" SortExpression="T_NO" />    
       <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="150px" DataField="FORMNAME" HeaderText="FORMNAME" HeaderStyle-CssClass="hideGridColumn" ItemStyle-CssClass="hideGridColumn" />
       <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="150px" DataField="STATUS" HeaderText="STATUS" HeaderStyle-CssClass="hideGridColumn" ItemStyle-CssClass="hideGridColumn" />
     </Columns>
 </asp:GridView>
```

//aspx.cs

```
protected void gvCustomers_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
   string T_NO = gvCustomers.SelectedRow.Cells[1].Text;
   string Status = gvCustomers.SelectedRow.Cells[3].Text;
   if (Status=="sent")
   {
    string message = "Do you want to Submit?";
    System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
    sb.Append("return confirm('");
    sb.Append(message);
    sb.Append("');");
    ClientScript.RegisterOnSubmitStatement(this.GetType(), "alert", 
    sb.ToString());
   } 
 }
```

Any idea on how to achieve this will be appreciated.

Comment: what is the problem with your code? Did your selected index change event execute?

Comment: @Alander yes selected index change event execute but pop up not

Comment: Your alert is not showing now, that's the problem. I'm I right?

Comment: have a look at this: https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Server-Side-Code-Behind-Yes-No-Confirmation-Message-Box-in-ASPNet.aspx

You wont be able to do what you want with pure server side code

Answer (score 0):

Use `OnRowDataBound` event for gridview to bind your java script function.

```
protected void myGridView_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e) 
{ 
  if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow) 
   {
     DataRowView drv = (DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem;
     e.Row.Attributes.Add("onclick", "selectedindexchanged()");
   }
}
```

Create a `selectedindexchanged` javascript function in Html `<head>` tag like this.

```
<script>
    function selectedindexchanged(){}
</script>
```

Now when you click on a grid view row, the selectedindexchanged will be called. This will help you to Show your alert message.